# Get primalforms dialog box results in powershell

Tags: powershell

From a PS script, I am calling a primalforms dialog box err.ps1, but I don't know how to return to the main script which button the users clicked on err.ps1 (Yes/No).

```
if (.{.\errDestination.ps1})
```

Doesn't seem to return the value being true as yes or false as no...

Any idea where should I set the return result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the generated code a bit to return the `DialogResult`. I put this at the bottom:

```
#endregion Generated Form Code

# ....

#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

return $form1.DialogResult

} #End Function

#Call the Function
return GenerateForm
#endregion
```

To evaluate it form the calling script:

```
$result = & .\errDestination.ps1
if ($result -eq "Yes") {
    # Yes
} else {
    # No
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, if I have to button Yes and No, what should I be looking for as an answer, I tried if (.{. \errDestination.ps1} -eq "Yes") but it doesn't seem to work, I also tried with True....

Comment: @JPBoucher Check out the documentation of that property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx). I also updated my answer with an example.